# How can I get the Netbeans plugin eslint to work?

Tags: node.js, netbeans-8, eslint

This was my process

- Install node.js/npm https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm
- Install eslint npm i -g eslint
- Go to Tools -> Options -> HTML/JS -> ESLint
- Set ESLint path to C:\Program Files\nodejs
- Set Conf path to Z:.eslintrc.json

There are no Action Items for ESLint, however when I run it from the command line, I get errors for the file.

Answer (score 6):

I configured in this way in **ubuntu 16.04** and **Netbeans 8.2**

1. After follow your steps
2. I searched where was installed my **eslint** (at my case at **/usr/bin/eslint**)

   [image]
3. You need a config eslint file (I create one at my home folder a file **.eslintrc.json**)

```json
{
   "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            3
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
           "error",
           "unix"
       ],
        "no-console": "off",
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
       ]
    }
}
```

4. My config in netbeans is like this:

   [image]
5. And when you check the code is (when you move the mouse over the red segment it shows the errors):

   [image]

Hope this help you

Greetings

Comment: Not working for me and i am also ubuntu 16.04 and Netbeans 8.2

Comment: netbeans source -> format is not compatible with eslint --fix

Comment: This answer helped.  AND I had to get eslint working on the command line.  Go to project folder and try `eslint path/to.js` and if an error shows, Google it.  The fuller command to try is `/usr/bin/eslint --config /some/path/.eslintrc --format compact .`